# Compare two dictionaries with equal keys but different values

Tags: c#

I am facing a brutal mental battle with myself! I am developing a laundry system, and in this system I have 4 tables where they are: Entry, Entry Item, Output and Item output.

in the table item entry and item output I have a method that sums all the pieces made in the input and output, if the sum beat is right but if it is different I wanted to find out what the code of the clothes and the quantity that is divergent. It is in this part that I am caught.

Table **ClothesOut**

[image: Table ClothesOut]

Table **ItenEntry**

[image: Table ItenEntry]

Table **ItemOut**

[image: Table ItemOut]

This is the example I'm trying to do:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Dictionary
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var d1 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            var d2 = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            d1.Add(1, 10);
            d1.Add(2, 20);

            d2.Add(1, 10);
            d2.Add(2, 5);

            var keyAndValue = d1.Zip(d2, (first, second) => first + " " + second);

            foreach (var item in keyAndValue)
            { 
               // I need to compare the value of d1 with the value of d2. if it is different bring the difference.
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh boy, this is gonna be SLOW as hell! Why don't you create a stored procedure in your DB and use some SQL joins to make it return the result set you need? Alternatively, you can use linq but that's gonna be way slower than the stored procedure.

Comment: He right, in others words, you dont have to load of your data in the application, except if youwant to work with a cache OR by working with all data each X hours for exemple.

Comment: hello all, it's true had not thought about the stored procedure. I will try this solution and put the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ to join two dictionaries. I'm not sure what operations you want to perform on unmatched records.

```
var query =
       from _d1 in d1
       join _d2 in d2 on _d1.Key equals _d2.Key
       where _d1.Value != _d2.Value
       select new { _d1, _d2 };


foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key:{item._d1.Key} Value 1: {item._d1.Value}, Value 2: {item._d2.Value}");
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: I agree with @Hirasawa Yui. If possible try writing stored procedure to load and filter data.

Comment: pushkin, with this code I also managed to make the routine work as it has to be. thank you all!.